# Is there a maxLength or an alternative keyword in OpenAPI 3

Tags: swagger, openapi

In openapis.org OpenAPI 3.0(https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.1.0), I am unable to find **maxLength** keyword to denote the max length allowed for a datatype nor an alternate. Can anyone help, do I need to do it with **x-**?

Answer (score 5):

It's tricky to find it:

[4.4 Data Types](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.1.0#data-types) :

> As defined by the [JSON Schema Validation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-bhutton-json-schema-validation-00#section-7.3) vocabulary, data types can have an optional modifier property: format. OAS defines additional formats to provide fine detail for primitive data types.

[JSON Schema Validation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-bhutton-json-schema-validation-00#section-7.3):
This document contains the description for *maxLength*

> [6.3.1.  maxLength](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-bhutton-json-schema-validation-00#section-6.3.1)
> The value of this keyword MUST be a non-negative integer.
> A string instance is valid against this keyword if its length is less
> than, or equal to, the value of this keyword.
> The length of a string instance is defined as the number of its
> characters as defined by RFC 8259 [RFC8259].

It's easier to find the documentation in [OpenAPI Version 3.0.3](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/)